# Retrieving Django model value based on another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I was following a youtube's django database model queries but try doing it with different context to see if I understand the model concept and not just blindly following (and it turns out i do not understand it at all).

I was trying to retrieve the "views" values in the model based on the tag name.
I manage to pull the individual item but i do not know how to retrieve the view count based on the tag name.

The table look similar to this:

| title | author | body | views | tags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| title a | author a | blog post a | 10 | apple, orange, pear |
| title b | author a | blog post b | 100 | banana, orange |
| title c | author a | blog post c | 50 | banana, pear, apple, orange |
| title d | author a | blog post d | 1 | grape |

the value i hope to retrieve is the sum of views that the tags are associated, like this
tags|count
--|--
apple|60
orange|160
banana|150
grape|1
pear|51

This is the current model

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Blogs"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} | {self.author} | {self.date_created}'
```

By running `a = Blog.objects.all()` in the shell i can retrieve the views by indexing a (`a[0].views`), but that only return the views of the particular blog, how do I return the view counts based on tag associated with the blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`Sum` function [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#sum) to sum the `views` of the related `Blog` instances. You can do this by passing the default related query name (`<model_name_in_lowercase>`) along with `__` being used to traverse the relationship, i.e. `blog__views` to `Sum`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum


tags = Tag.objects.annotate(view_sum=Sum('blog__views'))

for tag in tags:
    print(tag.name, tag.view_sum)
```

Comment: nice, that work.

But on another case, If I were to pull back objects that are not int/float can cannot be sum, how do I approach that?